# Is there any way to retrieve user stories with Facebook Javascript SDK?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-graph-api

Ok before this question be marked as answered on

> [Is there an API to retrieve Facebook recent activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6663779/is-there-an-api-to-retrieve-facebook-recent-activity)

I posted there my question plus some extra info and it got deleted marked as a seperate question so i am posting it here cause i think this isnt asnwered yet.

When requesting the /me/feed with the FB.API method i get all the news, including some fragments of data about user stories...

one example response is bellow.

(ps those fragments of data are NOT displayed with just using the graph api from the browser or the test console .....just only within the javascript SDK)

```
Object { name="Pages", id="2530096808"}

id
"2530XXX08"

name
"Pages"

comments
Object { count=0}

count
0

created_time
"2011-08-26T15:23:32+0000"

from
Object { name="Someone", id="51XXX98"}

id
"511XXX8"

name
"Someone"

id
"5XXXX498_10150271238528499"

type
"status"

updated_time
"2011-08-26T15:23:32+0000"
```

This information includes just the id of the user and the facebook page application reference(not the page the user liked just the application:pages).

Originaly inside facebook this postId was a mini story of (User liked some page) So.... as soon as i get these responses with javascript sdk souldn't be a way to get this info??? Else there is no meaning getting this info from the /me/feed request.......

There must be some functionality for this! cant be!

Its bothering me a whole week now if someone has any clue i would be gracefull!

p.s I looked over ther real time updates API but it does not give this info, it gives info only about changes in data.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
  alert(response.name);
});
```

after user has logged in.

you can type in any graph api command here

/me/home
/me/friends
etc...

for complete ref for graph api check this link

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: Yes thats the way i am using the graph api inside javascript SDK but there is no graph api reference about fetching user stories.
And as i mentioned before i get some parts of user stories requesting  /me/home from the graph api.
If you read carefully the response you will understand.
(again i am looking for a way to find stories like -> X is now friends with Y , A likes also the page xPaGe , etc....)